# Spark - yarn master but dataset on different hdfs cluster

Tags: apache-spark

I wish to run spark on one hdfs cluster (yarn master) but wish to access dataset from another hdfs cluster.

Both the hdfs cluster are keberized and the same ID has access on both.

steps:

1. *setup env for first hdfs cluster*
2. spark-shell --master yarn-client
3. sc.textFile("hdfs://[secondshdfscluster][dataset there]
4. res0.count(*) gives
   ......
   Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Client cannot authenticate via:[TOKEN,KERBEROS]
   .....

Is what I am trying even possible ? If so, any suggestions to fix it ?